# How do i allow the user to input 6 digits instead of 4

Tags: python, numbers

My code currently allows the user to input 4 numbers, i want to allow 6, how do i do this, ive tried editing the < 4 to a 6 but i legit just cant get my head around it, i also want the user to be able to only input 4 numbers if they wish, but i need the program to ask for 6

```
    import itertools
    nums = []

    while len(nums) < 4:
try:
    num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    if num not in range(10):
        raise ValueError
    else:
        nums.append(num)
except ValueError:
    print("Only integers 0-9 allowed!")

for x in itertools.permutations(nums):
print(''.join(str(n) for n in x)) `
```

Comment: Hi, so you want the user to input either 4 or 6 numbers. But the program should only proceed if 6 numbers were entered? How about: Let user enter 4 numbers and 5th time he enters nothing to indicate he is finished and the program stops. In case User does enter a 5th number program also waits for 6th number and proceeds. Is this something you are interested in?

Comment: Yeah David that’s exactly what i want! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what I believe you want to achieve (not most elegant but still):

```
nums = []
print('You need to enter minimum 4 digits and upto 6')
while len(nums) < 6:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a digit 0-9:"))
        if num not in range(10):
            raise ValueError
        else:
            nums.append(num)
            if 3 < len(nums) < 6:
                if input("Add more digits? [y/n]") != 'y':
                    break
    except ValueError:
        print("Only integers 0-9 allowed!")

print(nums)
```

You can modify your input request for digit based on len(nums) by giving option to stop so it feels better for user, though it requires a bit more coding.

Answer (score 0):

Looked like python code to me - didnt programm in python since a while. Maybe you need to do some adjustments.

You could try it like this:

```
import itertools
nums = []

try:
    while len(nums) < 4:
        num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
        if num not in range(10):
            raise NotANumberError
        nums.append(num)

    num = int(input("Enter a number or anything else to quit:"))
    if num not in range(10):
        raise ManualQuitError
    nums.append(num)

    num = int(input("Enter last number:"))
    if num not in range(10):
        raise NotANumberError
    nums.append(num)

except NotANumberError:
    print("Only integers 0-9 allowed!")
except ManualQuitError:
    print("You manually quit after 4 digits entered!")

for x in itertools.permutations(nums):
    print(''.join(str(n) for n in x)) `
```

Be aware the code still smells bad to me:

- could be more DRY
- could be less relying on exceptions for "normal" workflow

Comment: This is brilliant David thank you so much, could i ask, is there any way of preventing output numbers from being repeated?

Comment: Oh, I just took the printing you provided. Maybe this will work `print(nums)` instead of last two lines of code in example.

Comment: That gives me just a simple horizontal list of numbers entered by the user, e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: Its hard to guess what you are after. If you want the values printed being unique f.i. 4,7,8,9,4,7 => 4,7,8,9, then i would simply use a set (array with non duplicated values) `nums = set()` and `nums.add(num)` not an array - bear in mind this will ask user for 4 - 6 unique digits. Alternatively once you are printing you can transfer all value from array to set and print the set.